# Where is the bundled `python` executable in OpenOffice, in general?

Tags: python, openoffice

As described [in the Apache OpenOffice wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_bridge#PyUNO_bridge_modes), OpenOffice should be bundled with its own version of Python, which on Windows is located by default at `C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org <version>\program\python.exe`.

Where is this Python executable located on other platforms? Where (if anywhere) is this location formally documented?

Comment: `OpenOffice.org` is deprecated. Did you mean Apache OpenOffice or LibreOffice, or both?

Comment: @JimK I copied that more or less verbatim from the wiki page. The question is about Apache OpenOffice, and its apparently very-out-of-date wiki/docs.

Comment: Which wiki page? The page you linked says either "Apache OpenOffice" or refers to older versions such as "OpenOffice.org 2.0 and later", both of which are correct. ("OOo" short for OpenOffice.org can be seen in images, which is understandable since those are hard to keep up to date, but the images are functionally still accurate). And from https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python: "Apache OpenOffice 4 ships with the Python scripting language, version 2.7."

Answer (score 1):

> Where (if anywhere) is this location formally documented?

Nowhere as far as I know. Are you trying to do a system call at the specific location? It sounds risky because it might be in a slightly different place from what you expect. Maybe if you give more details about your goal then there would be a different way to accomplish it, such as environment variables.

The location on Windows is `(AOO or LO Program Files directory)\program\python.exe`.

Linux has system-wide versions of python so AOO and LO do not ship their own. However on those systems, an additional package may be required such as `libreoffice-script-provider-python`.

According to https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/where-is-the-python-executable-embedded-in-libreoffice-on-macos/50042/7, one user found it here on a Mac:

> `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/Resources/python`

**EDIT**:

LO and AOO can be installed in different locations on your system, and both can be installed at the same time, so you need to specify which location to use.

To run Python for LibreOffice on Windows, I use the following batch script. It adds paths where libraries are located from my extension, which may not be needed in your case.

```
c:
@rem chdir "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\OpenOffice 4\program\"
@rem chdir "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\LibreOffice 5\program\"
chdir "%ProgramFiles%\LibreOffice\program\"

set ADD_ON=C:\MyExtensionPath
@rem "." is the current directory and is needed to import uno for AOO.
set PYTHONPATH=%ADD_ON%\pythonpath;%ADD_ON%\tests\pythonpath;.

python.exe %1
```

I also use a shell script for Ubuntu. It's much shorter because it uses the system wide python.

```
export PYTHONPATH=.:../pythonpath:./pythonpath
python3 $1
```

In either case, if the python script is planning to connect to LibreOffice (which is normally why you would run a script with UNO), then LibreOffice needs to be started listening on a socket.

```
start soffice -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp; %1
```

Now if you are running the python script from within LibreOffice instead of externally, then none of this is necessary because LibreOffice already knows about its own version of python.

Comment: The reason for the question was that it's supposed to be possible (according to the wiki page I linked) to run a standalone Python script that interacts with OpenOffice. So the goal was just to find the bundled Python executable, so as to run the script and have proper access to the `uno` package.

Comment: In that case, see my edited answer.